# Linear combination of maximal minors is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This seems to be a simple linear algebra fact, but I cannot seem to prove it:

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be an $n$ by $n-1$ matrix whose entries are in a commutative ring $R$. Let $\Delta_i$ be $(-1)^i$ times the maximal minor obtained by deleting the $i$th row of $A$. Then $$a_{1i}\Delta_1 + \dots + a_{ni}\Delta_n =0$$ for all $i$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I meant row, thanks. I changed it above.

Comment: It is not true without alternating signs; try $A=\binom11$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $(-1)^{1-n}a_{1,i}\Delta_1 + \dots + (-1)^{n-n}a_{n,i}\Delta_n$ is the determinant of the $n\times n$ matrix obtained by copying column $i$ of $A$ (which contains those entries $a_{1,i},\ldots,a_{n,i}$) and adding it to $A$ as final column $n$; the determinant being computed by Laplace expansion along that final column. The resulting matrix has two equal columns, so its determinant is zero.